# Transparent Circle Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image][image]

Hello , can somebody say me how to make in adobe-illustrator white circle transparent in center of red background?

Comment: Please show what us you've tried and where you need help, this isn't a tutorial on demand site.

Comment: I don't now how to make center of that background transparent in adobe illustrator

Comment: In center of red background i want to make like 1 photo

Comment: Do you want to make a hole? If yes, select both and goto Pathfinder->MinusFront.

Comment: Are trying to do that with a raster image in Illustrator or is it all vector objects? do you know the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Various ways to do it, but this is the simplest:

1. Draw a red square, then draw a circle on top of the red sqaure.
2. Then go to Pathfinder (if it's not on your screen already then go to Window -> Pathfinder), and click on Minus Front

Whatever is in front will be taken away from the object in the back.